# k means clustering of ip address data in matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, ip-address, k-means

I have ip address data. I  want to apply k mean clustering on it. how to apply it. can  I map data in 4 dimensional space i.e. data has

```
10.0.11.4 
10.0.7.4 
10.0.8.4
10.0.14.4
```

then can I map data as 4 dimension i.e.

```
10  0  11  4 
10  0  7   4 
10  0  8   4
10  0  14  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a terrible idea to do so. It will lead quite meaningless clusters (Close IPs are often not related and host multiple sites. So the same IP might host a legal car shop and illegal material).

Did you know that **every IP is *one* number**?

The four-numbers-with-dots is just a bit easier to use for manual network management. But what you see is simply a **four-byte integer**. The IP `127.0.0.1` written in hex is `0x7F000001` and as decimal `2130706433`.

I haven't recently verified this, but I'm pretty sure all browser still have to support the decimal notion of IPs, too. If you have a webserver on you localhost, try accessing it via [`http:// 2130706433/`](http://2130706433/), or try `ping  2130706433` on the command line.

K-means on the four-bytes data space would only make sense if there were some pattern to how IP adresses are assigned. I.e. you would *need* to have 10.**1**.123.45 and 10.**2**.123.45 to always have as much in common as if they were subsequent IPs in the last byte.

Comment: This is already implemented in ieee paper i.e. "Wang, Jing, et al. "Network anomaly detection: A survey and comparative analysis of stochastic and deterministic methods." Decision and Control (CDC), 2013 IEEE 52nd Annual Conference on. IEEE, 2013". I am referring that paper. ip address data file in .mat  https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wptzvbkp77ehkp/nv1d.mat?dl=0      and in text    https://www.dropbox.com/s/vjuiiv9j9f3bixc/nv1d.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

It depends on why you want to do that.

For example if you want to do this to check which IP address are in the subnet or are geographically closest then K-means will clearly fail there. Because the following values (for exmple) as per k-means

`10.0.4.1
9.0.4.1`

are close to each other but in reality, they might geographically too far. So as I said, it all depends on why you want to run K-means on IP addresses?

Comment: Actually I am doing anomaly detection and for that I have data with ip address, flow size  and other features. so I want to apply k mean clustering on ip address  and want to characterize flow with output of k mean clustering , flow size and other features and then want to use this characterize flow  to input for an anomaly detection algorithm.

Comment: Well in that case you should not use IP address at all for clustering. Keep it out of your k-means algorithm, only use features which are numeric. Use ip address as a categorical attribute.

Comment: my professor will not allowed to not use ip address.after clustering i am making single value of these ip address e.g. 256 and then using this value so for each i.p. address one value will form. so i want how to cluster these data. can i map in 4 dimension space i.e. 1st no. of ip on X axis, then 2nd no. of ip on Y axis , 3rd no. on Z axis and 4th np. of ip on K axis so like these map all ip addresses on XYZK plane